# How is computer with FPU classified in Flynn's taxonomy?

Tags: parallel-processing, computer-science, cpu-architecture

How is computer with FPU classified in Flynn's taxonomy? If machine has a CPU with single core, but also has FPU, is that SISD or SIMD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your FPU also a vector unit, or does one FPU instruction result in only one floating-point operation?  (Or one FMA = 2 FLOPs; that would still be SISD because there's only one result, not multiple parallel results).

On many modern CPUs "the FPU" is short-hand for the hardware that includes the SIMD vector unit.

---

A single instruction will only trigger computation in the integer registers *or* the FPU; that's not SIMD.  (Unless it's a SIMD vector instruction.)

Superscalar (multiple instructions per cycle) isn't SIMD either; and it's not even MIMD.  The leading S refers to instruction *streams*, so finding and exploiting ILP to run multiple instructions per cycle from a single thread is not something that the taxonomy covers.  (Besides SIMD width, it's the other major dimension of single-threaded performance, though.)

Comment: Re last line: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar_processor), "In Flynn's taxonomy, a single-core superscalar processor is classified as an SISD processor (Single Instruction stream, Single Data stream), though many superscalar processors support short vector operations and so could be classified as SIMD (Single Instruction stream, Multiple Data streams). A multi-core superscalar processor is classified as an MIMD processor (Multiple Instruction streams, Multiple Data streams)."

Comment: Thanks. What if that machine has x86 architecture? Does it change anything?

Comment: @mazurro: x86 has SIMD built-in to the FPU in all CPUs that support MMX and later, literally shadowing the x87 registers.  And modern x86 does scalar FP using the low element of SIMD vector registers, `xmm` (SSE and SSE2, baseline for x86-64).  So anyway no, it doesn't change anything, my answer already covers the case of a SIMD-capable FPU, and I had x86 in mind when writing it.